# How to merge multiple update query as a single update query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario to update 'NULL' string if column has no value that means null. So, i ran multiple update query to set the 'NULL' string.

```
update codesets set system_name='NULL' where system_name is null
update codesets set column_name='NULL' where column_name is null
update codesets set table_name='NULL' where table_name is null
update codesets set schema_name='NULL' where schema_name is null
```

How to merge multiple update query as a single update query ?

Comment: Why do that at all? NULL exists for a reason. If there is no system name, it is null. If you want to seee the string 'NULL' instead, select the data accrdingly: `SELECT COALESCE(system_name, 'NULL'), ... FROM codesets`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use case expressions, or nvl, or coalesce:

```
update codesets
set system_name=coalesce(system_name, 'NULL'),
    column_name=coalesce(column_name, 'NULL'),
    table_name=coalesce(table_name, 'NULL'),
    schema_name=coalesce(schema_name, 'NULL')
where system_name is null
or column_name is null
or table_name is null
or schema_name is null
```

For each row that is updated, each of those column is (re)set to its current value if it is not null, and to 'NULL' if it is.

The combined `where` clause means that only rows where at least one column needs to be updated are touched; for those rows all four columns are updated, but might be to their original values. At least one column will change though.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TvwtFPaT)

I'd question whether this is a good idea though - using the magic value 'NULL' instead of a true null seems unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `coalesce` to set the values to 'NULL', but I don't see the point in doing that, the code seems to be less readable this way (in my opinion).

Here's an example code:

```sql
update codesets 
set 
system_name=coalesce(system_name, 'NULL'),
column_name=coalesce(column_name, 'NULL'),
table_name=coalesce(table_name, 'NULL'),
schema_name =coalesce(schema_name , 'NULL') 
where 
system_name is null or column_name is null or table_name is null or schema_name is null
```

And also, why do you need to set the values to 'NULL'?